# Circumference debugging in Java

Tags: javascript, debugging, syntax-error

```
var circumferenceOfCircle = function(r) {
    console.log( "2*3.14*" r "=" (2*3.14*r) ) } ;

circumferenceOfCircle(3)
```

I am a beginner at javascript and wanted to make a simple circumference function. However, when I submit this code, I get a SyntaxError, `missing ) after argument list`.

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the `+` in the `console.log` when you are concatenating the strings.

```js
var circumferenceOfCircle = function(r) {

    console.log( "2*3.14*"+r+"="+(2*3.14*r));
};
circumferenceOfCircle(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the concatenation +, you'd write:

```js
function circumferenceOfCircle(r) {
    console.log( "2*3.14*" + r + "=" + (2*3.14*r) );
};
circumferenceOfCircle(3);
```